# Using find() in a vector of maps, C++

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, iterator, find

For my class, I need to find usage for the following structure: `vector<map<int, map<char, float>>>`

My idea was to create a basic encryption method, that's output depends on the date of use (each day has its own coding for the characters throughout the year). The outer `map` of the `vector` represents the months, and the `int` key of those maps represent the days.

The construction uses a [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l85tojqj0op85jk/abc.txt?dl=0), where each line has the ABC listed and for each letter belongs a number separated by a semicolon.

My code works but only gives the encryption for 1st of each month, no matter what date it receives. The `<<` operator works properly.

```
class CodeCollection{
    vector<map<int, map<char, float>>> coding_of_the_day;

public:
    CodeCollection(string path){
        ifstream fin(path);
        if(!fin.is_open()){
            cerr << "Nope" << endl;
            exit(432);
        }
        for(size_t j = 0; j < month_lenght.size(); ++j){ 
            int day = 1;
            map<int, map<char, float>> month;
            for(int i = 0; i < month_lenght[j]; ++i){
                map<char, float> char_value;
                char c, tmp;
                float f;
                string abc_coding;
                while(getline(fin, abc_coding)){
                    stringstream ss;
                    ss << abc_coding;
                    int counter = 1;
                    while(ss.good()){
                        ss >> c >> tmp >> f >> tmp;
                        char_value.emplace(c, f);
                        cout << c << f << " " << day << counter << endl;
                        counter++;
                    }
                    month.emplace(day, char_value);
                    day++;
                }
            }
            coding_of_the_day.push_back(month);
        }
        fin.close();
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, map<int, map<char, float>>& monthly){
        for(auto const& first_key : monthly){
            out << first_key.first;
            for(auto const& second_key : first_key.second){
                out << second_key.first << " = " << second_key.second << ", ";
            }
            out << endl;
        }
        return out;
    }

    ofstream codegenerator(string message, int month, int day){
        ofstream fout("code.txt");
///I suppose  my flaw is here:
        map<int, map<char, float>>::iterator it = coding_of_the_day[month-1].find(day); 
        for(size_t i = 0; i < message.size(); ++i){
            map<char, float>::iterator ite = it->second.find(message[i]);
            fout << ite->second << ".";
        }
        return fout;
    }
};
```

Thank you for any kind of solution in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to find in this large structure?

Comment: Why not a `map` if you want to look these up quickly? As a note, this "encryption" method seems extraordinarily flimsy so I hope this is just for academic purposes.

Comment: I'd suggest checking the return value of `find` before dereferencing it.

Comment: From a C++ perspective you may want to implement encryption as a writable stream that emits a readable stream of output.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I want to find the given day that define which ```map``` of coding needs to be used

Comment: Hint: `std::map<date_type, map<...>>`

Comment: Please look at the page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and show us how you construct `coding_of_the_day`.

Comment: @tadman Yes, for academic purposes. With a ```map``` it would be way easier.

Comment: Well, `map` is the way to make a look-up table. Alternatively if you can express the dates as integers that are 0-indexed, an array or `std::vector`.

Comment: Halfway there. Could you show us the file you use to initialize the `CodeCollection`, or better still [reduce it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to a single month of two days (the 1st and 2nd) and a code book that encrypts only one letter, and show us that?

Comment: @Beta Please find the link of the file above. 
I'm not 100% sure what you mean by code book, but with the example file used here letter 'a' would have a structure like this inside the vector on 1st January: ```map<1, map<a,1>>```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't test your constructor. Here:

```
for(int i = 0; i < month_lenght[j]; ++i){
  map<char, float> char_value;
  ...
  char_value.emplace(c, f);
  ...
  month.emplace(day, char_value);
  day++;
}
```

The trouble is that `emplace` doesn't overwrite, it *defers* to prior values. If you try to `emplace` an entry with a key for which there is already an entry in the map, the new element is discarded. So once you have a value assigned to 'a' in `char_value` for day 1, you can't change it for day 2.

Easy to solve:

```
for(int i = 0; i < month_lenght[j]; ++i){
  char_value.clear();
  ...
```